# How to pass a value to the list box to another class

Tags: c#

I have to called a method `Run` in the `Class1`. And now I try to return `str` to listbox `Running`. I know this code `Running.Items.Add(str);` is not correct because it is in a different class. Please tell me how to fix it?

**Class1.cs**

```
class Class1
{
    public void Run()
    {
        string str = "Hello";
        Running.Items.Add(str);
    }
}
```

**Form1.cs**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Running_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

> Update How do I call a class method

**Form1**

```
    public void Invoke(string typeName, string methodName)
    {
        Type type = Type.GetType(typeName);
        object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(methodName);
        method.Invoke(instance, null);
    }

    private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Task(() => { Invoke("Worker." + name, "Run"); }).Start();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show how you call `Run()`, so I'm going to assume you do so from `Form1`.

You need to pass a reference one way or the other. Making your class `Class1` dependent on your form is a bad idea. You can make it dependent on the lsitbox, and rename it accordingly:

```
public class ListBoxAdder()
{
    private ListBox _listBox;
    public ListBoxAdder(ListBox listBox)
    {
        _listBox = listBox;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        string str = "Hello";
        _listbox.Items.Add(str);
    }
}
```

Then call it from your form and pass the reference to the `Running` ListBox:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var listBoxAdder = new ListBoxAdder(this.Running);
        listBoxAdder.Run();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Now I will try your code. I added the update to my question with an explanation of how I call 'Run'

Comment: No, you don't need reflection for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the `str` object to the `Running` list in the class `class1` you should just get a reference to the active form of the `Form1` :

```
public void Run()
{
      string str = "Hello";
      ((Form1)Form1.ActiveForm).Running.Items.Add(str);
}
```

Comment: By binding the `Class1` to `Form1` you're actively preventing code reuse.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I got a warning, 'Running' is not available due to its protection level. I tried to change 'private' -> 'public', but it did not help.

Comment: @CodeCaster indeed I'm, I'm just giving a fast answer for a fast question

Comment: @user3650075 just change the modifier of the Running listbox in it's properties, try to rebuild, it should work